# OOP, private functions inside a top level method of the namespace

Tags: javascript, oop, private-members, javascript-namespaces

I have a js script which declares a namespace, then has a method called `run()` which I can call from inside a XUL script like `myNamespace.run()`:

```
var myNamespace = {
    run: function() {
        var selectedText = getSelText();
        alert (selectedText);

        var getSelText = function() {
            var focusedWindow = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow;
            var selText = focusedWindow.getSelection();

            return selText.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to call `getSelText()` inside `myNamespace.run()` without needing to declare `getSelText()` as another top level function of `myNamespace`. Instead, it should be like a private method inside `myNamespace.run()`.

When I run this script I receive an error:

> `getSelText` is not a function.

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, so I don't know the best way of designing this. Is it possible to acheive what I am trying? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare `getSelText` as a `var`, it needs to come before any statements where you use it. Just make the `var getSelText = ...` statement the first statement in the `run` function.

---

**Supplemental information:**

`var` statements in Javascript are "hoisted" to top of the function they're declared in, so this:

```
function() {
    var a = 42;
    // Other stuff...
    var b = 23; 
}
```

really means this:

```
function() {
    var a = 42, b;
    // Other stuff...
    b = 23;
}
```

Another similar construct in Javascript is the function statement, as opposed to function expressions:

```
function() {
    var fn1 = function() { return fn2(); }; // Function expression
    alert(fn1());

    // Function statement
    function fn2() {
        return "Hello from fn2";
    }
}
```

If you ran the code above, it would successfully alert "Hello from fn2". This is because function statements are hoisted to the tip-top before any other statement within the scope they're declared in. As you can see, this could get very confusing. Probably the best convention to follow is to use function expressions and declare them in the order that you need.

Comment: thanks for the info! Also found out I could declare functions without the var statement and call them inside run()

Comment: one small nitpick, variables are hoisted to top, but the initialization is not. `b` is `undefined` in your example if "other stuff" accesses it. Then it's set to `23`. You're right that function statements will work if used before they're created (in scope.)

Comment: Thanks! I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 7):

It's called the module pattern. Create an anonymous function (for scoping) that gets called immediately and return the public interface.

```
var myNamespace = (function() {
  // private functions for your namespace
  var getSelText = function() {
        ...
  };

  return {
    run: function() {
        var selectedText = getSelText();
        alert (selectedText);
    }
  };
})()
```